Why C# Extension IntelliSense does not working in VS Code? C# Unity
At first, it does not work at all, but after enabling all Editor IntelliSense suggestions it works for some files. The IntelliSense will show an error if a class that the IntelliSense not working is used, as they say the type or namespace name could not be found.
I have tried downgrading the C# extensions, reinstalling the extensions, making new C# files via Unity, and copying & pasting the codes from the working one to the not working one.

By default, and as I know, VSCode IntelliSense is not as well as in Visual Studio, as Visual Studio has his own component for Unity development. However, there is an official extension (I don't know if is one of the ones you have already used as you mentioned) in VSCode Marketplace that works better for Unity development in VSCode. Here it is the extension. It shouldn't give you problems: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioToolsForUnity.vstuc
Also it could be useful the Unity Code Snippsets:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kleber-swf.unity-code-snippets
Hope this can help you :)

Yep that is the one I am using

Are you using also Unity Code Snippset extension? This also helps a lot!

I updated the post with new info :)

Finally solved the problem by setting external tools to VS Code and then regenerate project files
Full Source
